# Naming convention: looking for better terminology for "centrally symmetric smooth strictly convex bodies"

Tags: convex-geometry, terminology, convexity

I have recently found myself researching a certain type of convex body in $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely centrally symmetric smooth strictly convex bodies.
Instead of repeating such a sentence repetitively I have found myself referring to them as "symmetric bodies", but I was hoping there is a more widely used name for them.
I have checked the literature but cannot for the life of me find anything.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you could just say "in this article CSSSCB stands for centrally symmetric smooth strictly convex bodies?"

Comment: "symmetric convex body" is widely used to mean "centrally symmetric convex body", so I would add an extra adjective here. Maybe "regular symmetric (convex) body" ? (I have seen "regular" to mean "smooth and strictly convex", but it is not standard terminology)

Comment: You could try giving them your own name. Call them D-bodies.

Comment: @erz I did originally go with this but I found it isn't very nice to read every time.

Answer (score 1):

Centrally symmetric convex body which is absorbing is called "barrel" in the functional analysis. So I suggest you use this term (probably stating explicitly that the barrels you consider are smooth).

Comment: This will run into the same issue of me having to call them "strictly convex smooth barrels" which (while better) is still a bit of a mouthful.